# How to understand rails5's actioncable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

Recently I found that Rails5's ActionCable very interesting,So I want to dig into Rails5's ActionCable internels.But I didn't know where to begin.

I want someone pave the way for me:
eg: what's the difference between ActionCable and faye and message_bus..do they use the same protocol like websockets?

Comment: I documented the protocol here: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/action_cable_client#the-action-cable-protocol is that more of what you're looking for?